# name & icon of my app in task manager is not showing correct, java thread name is showing as parent process and my application as child process

Tags: java

In the task manager the name is showing as Java(SE) platform binary as parent thread and  my application name is showing as child thread

I am expecting that the name of application and custom icon on the task manager as parent thread[the name of my application is showing as child thread , I want it to be parent thread in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC7U9.jpg). If we see intellij , eclipse and other application also , they are able to rename their application name and description on the task manager . I was to implement the same into my enterprise project.

Comment: IntelliJ, Eclipse and the other applications have in common that they use a custom launcher. Windows shows the information from the executable in the task manager.

Comment: How to create a custom launcher for my requirement

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+create+a+custom+Java+launcher

Answer (score 0):

Java applications are not stand-alone executables, they comprise one or more Java class files. The Java compiler converts source files to class files by translating source code into Java byte codes, which can only run inside the Java Virtual Machine. So the Java VM will always be the parent of your class. I am not aware of any method of converting Java classes to executables, but Google may find you some suggestions.